# Loading resources to imported assembly

Tags: wpf, binding, resources, .net-assembly, mergeddictionaries

I have developed to applications a scheduler program and a library administration program.
The library admnistration needs some of the same features in the scheduler program so published the scheduler program on NuGet and installed it in the libray administration program and used the User Controls from the scheduler software here.
This works fine, except the translations from the scheduler don't get loaded when i use it in the library program. It works fine when i use the scheduler program on its own.

**In both programs i have created a ResourceDictionary like this**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:cultures="clr-namespace:LibraryAdministration.Cultures">

<!-- Resources ODP contains the current instance of the WPFLocalize.Properties.Resources class.
   Used in bindings to get localized strings and automatic updates when the culture is updated -->
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Resources" ObjectType="{x:Type cultures:CultureResources}" MethodName="GetResourceInstance"/>

<!-- CultureResources ODP provides access to list of currently available cultures -->
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="CultureResourcesDS" ObjectType="{x:Type cultures:CultureResources}"/>
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary 
          Source="pack://application:,,,/Administration;component/resourcedictionary.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**I load the resources in both programs like this**

```
{Binding Path=MainWindow_Title, Source={StaticResource Resources}}
```

**This is my Culture class in both applications**

```
public class CultureResources
{
    //only fetch installed cultures once
    private static bool bFoundInstalledCultures = false;

    private static List<CultureInfo> pSupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>();
    /// <summary>
    /// List of available cultures, enumerated at startup
    /// </summary>
    public static List<CultureInfo> SupportedCultures
    {
        get { return pSupportedCultures; }
    }

    public CultureResources()
    {
        if (!bFoundInstalledCultures)
        {
            //determine which cultures are available to this application
            Debug.WriteLine("Get Installed cultures:");
            CultureInfo tCulture = new CultureInfo("");
            foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(Application.StartupPath))
            {
                try
                {
                    //see if this directory corresponds to a valid culture name
                    DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
                    tCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(dirinfo.Name);

                    //determine if a resources dll exists in this directory that matches the executable name
                    if (dirinfo.GetFiles(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath) + ".resources.dll").Length > 0)
                    {
                        pSupportedCultures.Add(tCulture);
                        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(" Found Culture: {0} [{1}]", tCulture.DisplayName, tCulture.Name));
                    }
                }
                catch(ArgumentException) //ignore exceptions generated for any unrelated directories in the bin folder
                {
                }
            }
            bFoundInstalledCultures = true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Resources ObjectDataProvider uses this method to get an instance of the WPFLocalize.Properties.Resources class
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public LibraryAdministration.Cultures.Resources GetResourceInstance()
    {

        return new Resources();
    }

    private static ObjectDataProvider m_provider;
    public static ObjectDataProvider ResourceProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_provider == null)
                m_provider = (ObjectDataProvider)App.Current.FindResource("Resources");
            return m_provider;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change the current culture used in the application.
    /// If the desired culture is available all localized elements are updated.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="culture">Culture to change to</param>
    public static void ChangeCulture(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //remain on the current culture if the desired culture cannot be found
        // - otherwise it would revert to the default resources set, which may or may not be desired.
        if (pSupportedCultures.Contains(culture))
        {
            Resources.Culture = culture;
            ResourceProvider.Refresh();
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Culture [{0}] not available", culture));
    }
}
```

}

I know the problem is that the resources in the scheduler software isn't initialised, i tried to create a MergedDictionaries in my library app like this with no luck

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary 
          Source="pack://application:,,,/Administration;component/resourcedictionary.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Hope there is some one that can help me with this.

Thanks
Anders Mikkelsen

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding an ObjectDataProvider to my resourceDirectory.xaml in my library administration

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="CSResources" ObjectType="{x:Type CScultures:CultureResources}" MethodName="GetResourceInstance"/>
```

from my schduler administration

```
"xmlns:CScultures="clr-namespace:Administration.Cultures;assembly=Administration"
```

I named the key the same as i do in my scheduler administration.

Because there can't be 2 keys with the same value, I change the name of my resource to CSResource.